# I'm having trouble compiling ZSH manually without root

Tags: zsh

![Error message][1]

This occurs during make install. 'configure' and 'make' work fine. Though, all *.1 files in the Doc folder are of zero length.

http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00224.html

I used the above link as reference but even after deleting the .1 files it does not work.

Any suggestions?

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAz6z.png

Comment: When you write a question about an error, always, __always__ include details of the error. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Following your link and the follow-up post to that, I see that the possible cause of your error might be that `yodl` is missing. Did you already check for that? Deleting the `*.1` files is *not* the solution. It just has to be done in order to get `make` to rebuild them once `yodl` is available. The error message (BTW: Why not just copy and paste that as text?) shows that  `test -s ./$file || exit 1;` is to be run for each of the `*.1` files. `test -s` checks if a file exists and has non-zero length.